# how to create csv file for attribute and how to add attribute using csv file programmatically in magento 2

Tags: magento2

how to add csv file here

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'test_attribute',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Test Attribute',
                'input' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => 0,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
```

Comment: Have you find any solution?

Comment: not yet ! just added all attribute manually